# I can't use one of keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, languages, special-chars

In a non-english language (Persian) when I want to use a special character, I should tap on `shift` key (⇑) and then use the character. Other way is hold one special key to use the character. In second way, I can use the character, but in first way not.

---

Real happening: I tap on `Shift` and ‍`ع` for using char `غ`. I do this but instead of `غ`, char `ع` is written, but when I hold `ع`, char `غ` is writen and I want it.

---

Problem solved: I disable suggestion system and problem solved.

I use android 6 and system's default keyboard.

Excuse me if I describe badly :(

Comment: Are you talking about an on-screen keyboard or a physical keyboard?

Comment: On-screen keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried other keyboard apps?

Comment: Because of few space, I prefer to use system default.

Comment: Please note that there's no universal system's default keyboard since vendors can customize it. Thus, could you [edit] and mention the device model and the system's default keyboard? You can check the name from Settings - Languages & input - Current Keyboard.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!